# How to keep Carthage builds in source control to avoid need to "carthage update" for team?

Tags: xcode, xcode7, carthage

We have Carthage dependencies that take a very long time to fetch and build. I tried putting the `/Carthage/Builds` folder into source control and pointed the framework paths in the build settings to it, but the team is still forced to do `carthage update` for it to work, otherwise updated dependencies aren't recognized when pulling from source control (even the updated builds have been checked in).

Is there something I'm missing and not as simple as keeping the builds folder in source control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough to add the Builds folder into source control as you described. If you add the frameworks from there and defined your framework search path as `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Carthage/Build/iOS` (example for iOS) everything should work like a charm. In our project we configured it that way.

If not take a look into the build settings and search for the word carthage. Only result should be your framework search path. Maybe you defined some paths into `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Carthage/Checkouts` This may be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, one of the nested frameworks had an absolute path, so the solution was just to add an import path to it's *module.map*.

[image]